# How to switch keyboard backlight in MSI KATANA GF66 in ubuntu 22.04 when function keys for backlight does not work?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, backlight, keyboard-backlight

I've had my laptop (MSI KATANA GF66 12UEOK) since late 2022.
I'm using ubuntu for years, but the problem here was that the keyboard backlight function key assigned on the keyboard is not working in ubuntu (though the touchpad button does not work too, but it works in ubuntu 23.10)
I don't wanted to upgrade my 22.04 LTS version to 23.10, so I should have found a way to turn on the keyboard backlight and off using keyboard shortcuts.
I literally searched for weeks, around an hour each day, and i finally came up with the easiest way!
I will answer my question to help others not facing this problem again.
Notice that you can use this method if `openrgb` can control your keyboard backlight (turning it on/off or changing color, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I searched for weeks in keyboard drivers, using lots of things like `xkb`, `xmodmap`, and so on. But no one worked!

I have MSI KATANA GF66 and this worked for me perfectly and it will work for anyone if `openrgb` supports their keyboard backlight.

Follow these steps:

1. Install `openrgb` using these commands:
   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/openrgb -y`
   `sudo apt update`
   `sudo apt install openrgb`
2. Open `openrgb` app and set a color you like and save the profile named `on_color`
3. set the backlight off using the option of `off` in `openrgb` and save the profile as `off_color`
4. Add a custom keyboard shortcut in **Settings > Keyboard > View and Customize Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts** using `+` sign
5. Use a custom name like `openrgb backlight off` in name section.
   Use this command in the command section:
   `openrgb -p off_color`
   Use a favorite key combination like `Ctrl + Shift + Z`
6. Add another custom shortcut using `+` sign.
   Use a custom name like `openrgb backlight on` in name section.
   Use this command in the command section:
   `openrgb -p on_color`
   Use a favorite key combination like `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Z`

from now on you can  turn on/off the keyboard backlight using these keyboard shortcuts. (and you can add more colors as many as you like)

I searched for weeks in keyboard drivers, using lots of things like `xkb`, `xmodmap`, and so on. But no one worked!

I have MSI KATANA GF66 and this worked for me perfectly and it will work for anyone if `openrgb` supports their keyboard backlight.

Follow these steps:

1. Install `openrgb` using these commands:
   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/openrgb -y`
   `sudo apt update`
   `sudo apt install openrgb`
2. Open `openrgb` app and set a color you like and save the profile named `on_color`
3. set the backlight off using the option of `off` in `openrgb` and save the profile as `off_color`
4. Add a custom keyboard shortcut in **Settings > Keyboard > View and Customize Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts** using `+` sign
5. Use a custom name like `openrgb backlight off` in name section.
   Use this command in the command section:
   `openrgb -p off_color`
   Use a favorite key combination like `Ctrl + Shift + Z`
6. Add another custom shortcut using `+` sign.
   Use a custom name like `openrgb backlight on` in name section.
   Use this command in the command section:
   `openrgb -p on_color`
   Use a favorite key combination like `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + Z`

from now on you can  turn on/off the keyboard backlight using these keyboard shortcuts. (and you can add more colors as many as you like)